# Графика на чистом C++

Tags: c++, графика, sfml

Прочитал, что на C++ встроенными средствами нельзя отрисовывать графику. НО, ее можно отрисовывать с библиотекой SFML, которая написана на этих же плюсах.
Объясните, где логика спряталась?

Comment: от зоркого ока логику не спрячешь. действительно, почему все реализованные где-либо когда-либо алгоритмы не поместить в базовую библиотеку? от этого ведь она станет меньше, быстрее, и поддерживать её станет проще.

Comment: Я не говорю помещать их в базу. Я говорю о том, что такая возможность похоже есть.

Comment: Ну ответ прост: встроенными средствами нельзя, "невстроенными" - можно. SFML как раз и использует такие средства. Так-то в C++ и встроенных средств для создания GUI нет, но qt как-то же справляется с его созданием?

Comment: С чем взаимодействует C++ в библиотеке SFML, что позволяет отрисовывать графику?

Comment: @Александр насколько я вижу по исходникам, используется OpenGL: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/extlibs/headers/glad/include/glad/gl.h

Comment: Вызов API операционной системы, например — является ли "встроенным средством"?

Comment: @Harry  API операционной системы здесь нужен для создания и настройки окна. А то что будет рисоваться в этом окне уже с помощью графического API (opengl либо ещё какой-то) который даёт доступ к непосредственно к "рисователю" тоесть к видеокарте

Comment: @ampawd Да какая разница? Я о том, что ТС понимает под "*встроенными средствами С+*". API или сторонние библиотеки — принципиальной разницы с точки зрения "встроенных средств" не вижу.

Answer (score 6):

Вы основываетесь на ложной посылке — "*библиотекой SFML, которая написана на этих же плюсах*". Потому что она использует не только чистый, переносимый, ограниченный стандартом C++, но и обращения к сторонним библиотекам/API.

Если считать использование сторонних библиотек и API "встроенными средствами С++", то ваше заявление, что "*на C++ встроенными средствами нельзя отрисовывать графику*" — ложно. Если же использование сторонних библиотек и API не является "встроенными средствами С++", то ложна посылка, что библиотека SFML написана "на тех же плюсах".

Логика никуда не спряталась, согласно науке логике из ложной посылки может вытекать что угодно...

P.S. Любая дискуссия должна начинаться с точного недвусмысленного определения терминов и проверки истинности исходных посылок.

Answer (score 4):

Разные ОС предоставляют разные [волшебные библиотеки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2) (на винде - WinAPI, OpenGL, и прочие), которые корнями уходят куда-то глубоко в нутро ОС и в непосредственную работу с железом.

SFML, SDL2 и подобные - на каждой ОС вызывают ее родные средства работы с графикой.

Comment: Я и хочу знать, как это работает на уровне "корнями уходят куда-то глубоко в нутро ОС и в непосредственную работу с железом". Каждый ответ связан с использованием API. Когда писали саму ОС, какие API они использовали, если ОС не было? Куда они проводили системные вызовы?

Comment: Сейчас все пишется внутри ОС, используя эти самые "волшебные библиотеки". Захотел написать ОС, пишешь ее используй средства ОС. На ассемблере пишешь, используя ОС. Как выйти за рамки ОС?

Comment: @Александр Нагуглите туториалы по написанию своей ОС, там будет какая-то простенькая графика. Сложная графика - фиг, потому что тот же OpenGL реализуют производители видеокарт в своих драйверах, для каждой видеокарты отдельно. Без их поддержки или без длительного ковыряния разных моделей видеокарт.

Answer (score 1):

На чистом C++ ты можешь написать свою графику. Хотяя, ну почти на C++. Если быть немного человеком который любит мучения и использовать ассемблер с грязными ручками - можно вручную изменять видеопамять и рисовать что душе вздумается, но это сложно. (А ещё вряд-ли тебе просто так даст изменять видеопамять какая-либо ос)

Потому используют операционную систему. Она сама по себе выводит графическую информацию и делиться этой возможностью с другими программами в более простом интерфейсе. Прикол в том, что если ты хочешь писать кроссплатформенный код - придётся много трудиться. Ведь апи от винды не будет работать на линуксе, маке или анроиде. А таже sfml является кроссплатформенной т.е. код который ты написал будет работать на всех платформах и операционках, которые поддерживает эта библиотека.

Минус своей графики также в том, что тебе придётся делать всё с нуля. Казалось бы - нарисовать круг это так просто, но.. нет. Для этого тебе как минимум нужно знать алгоритм (Например: брезенхема), а если ты прогуливал алгебру с геометрией - лучше вообще забудь про свою графику, тк компьютерная графика - сплошная математика.

Делаем выводы: ты можешь сделать графику если хочешь, но стоит ли это того, когда есть зоопарк разных фреймворков и библиотек для этого? Вспомнить тот же qt, или если важна скорость - opengl. А если ты делаешь игру - почему-бы не использовать unreal engine который как раз использует C++? Сложно? Есть unity на шарпе.

Comment: "Потому используют операционную систему. Она сама по себе выводит графическую информацию и делиться этой возможностью с другими программами в более простом интерфейсе"- вот, очень хочу остановится на этом фрагменте. Что значит, что ОС сама по себе выводит графическую информацию?

Comment: Так же интересует, как написали сам OpenGL, с помощью которого можно отрисовывать графику? Цепочка, к примеру: Unreal Engine - QT - SFML - OpenGL - ?. Во всех этих пунктах, мы можем работать с графикой. Как выводилось изображение, как рисовались первые графические приложения, когда не было всей этой ванилщины, о которой мне написали выше? Как происходил весь этот нижнеуровневый хардкор?

Comment: Вообще - самая первая программа которая запускается на ПК - биос. В его задачи входят: запуск ос, нахождение всех устройств и создания интерфейса для их использования (Клавиатура, монитор, видеокарта, мышка итд). После ОС может использовать этот интерфейс  для своих нужд. В том числе и вывод графической информации. На нормальных ОС этот интерфейс для обычных приложений урезан или вообще отсутствует. (Из-за небезопасности)  Зато есть интерфейс от самой ОС (В windows, например, winapi) @Александр

Comment: Я думаю вы понимаете, что такие крупные и популярные библиотеки с фреймворками как: qt, sfml, opengl и другие устроены довольно сложно, потому нельзя сказать точно - что они там внутри себя используют. Как-то так Unreal Engine - QT - SFML - OpenGL - OC/? - bios - машинный код @Александр